# Como descobrir propriedades relevantes de uma base para algoritmo de classificação em Python?

Tags: python, algoritmo, machine-learning

Tenho uma base de dados(planilha do excel) sobre a saúde de idosos com cerca de 112 colunas e gostaria de saber qual o melhor algoritmo para extrair algumas dessas colunas, mantendo a variabilidade dos dados e não perdendo a referência ao nome das que foram selecionadas (**isso é possível?**).

Em testes anteriores, utilizei o *PCA* mas as componentes resultantes não possuem um nome significativo.

Para contextualizar, a ideia principal é utilizar um algoritmo que extraia as colunas da minha base de dados, de modo a eliminar a forte correlação entre elas, e posteriormente utilizar algum algoritmo de classificação (*k-means, DBSCAN*...) para classificar cada pessoa (saudável, não saudável, entre outros...).

Estou utilizando a biblioteca *scikit-learn* no momento

Comment: Não seria mais facil montar uma query no BD de consulta, apenas selecionando os campos que você precisa?

Comment: Na verdade estou trabalhando com um planilha do excel! De início selecionei apenas algumas colunas, mas ao conversar com um professor especializado em AM fui informado de que escolher as colunas aleatoriamente não é um bom caminho e que o correto seria utilizar algum algoritmo para isso.

Answer (score 0):

Igor. Tente utilizar algumas técnicas mais básicas de análise exploratória dos seus dados, como por exemplo carregar os dados em um dataframe do Pandas e tirar suas correlações com `data.corr()`. Essa função já calcula a correlação entre as colunas. Após isso você pode usar um mapa de calor (*heatmap*) para visualizar melhor suas correlações, e assim excluir as colunas que você julgar desnecessárias.

Talvez o post nesse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44889508/if-correlation-is-greater-than-0-75-remove-the-column-from-dataframe-of-pandas) pode te ajudar a automatizar isso.

Comment: Obrigado Matheus! Aparentemente o que você sugeriu pode funcionar, irei testar

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

sobre o PCA, acho que você teve um entendimento incorreto sobre o que ele se propõe a fazer. Ele é útil quando você deseja reduzir o número de dimensões de um conjunto de dados, pois transforma combinações dos atributos em um número menor de atributos e com a perda mínima de informação. Dessa forma, você poderia utilizar o PCA na sua base original e criar o classificador a partir dessa base gerada pelo PCA. Isso tem como vantagem a garantia da perda mínima de informação ao se retirarem colunas, mas a grande desvantagem é a dificuldade de interpretação.

Se você deseja apenas descobrir os campos menos influentes, pode utilizar métodos como SelectKBest.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest

Segue um artigo bem interessante sobre o tema: https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-selection-techniques-in-machine-learning-with-python-f24e7da3f36e